# how to install specific version of minetest?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04, ppa, downgrade

I upgraded an older Ubuntu computer to 20.04.  Everything went well.  But now the kids are telling me they cannot connect to their favourite minetest servers.  The game complains about
`Protocol version mismatch. Server supports protocol versions between 24 and 32. We support protocol versions between version 37 and 39.`  Looking it up, I see that minetest had a big change when it went from v0.4 to v5, and newer versions are not backwards compatible.

So I found a PPA that has both older and newer versions of minetest:  [https://launchpad.net/~minetestdevs/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eminetestdevs/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Of interest to me, it has this file:  [minetest_0.4.16-ppa5~ubuntu17.04.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Eminetestdevs/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+build/12683260/+files/minetest_0.4.16-ppa5%7Eubuntu17.04.1_amd64.deb) (7.2 MiB)

But...how do I install that version?  I added the PPA and tried variations of this:

```
> sudo apt-get install minetest=0.4.16
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.4.16' for 'minetest' was not found
```

If I leave out the version number I do see it install the *latest* version from that PPA.  But is there a way to force it to install an older version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @N0rbert No, none of those work.  I have the .deb file, but if I try to install it, there are missing dependencies, and when I run "apt-get install -f" to fix the missing dependencies, it then upgrades to the latest minetest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then let's download 0.4.16 from official *bionic* repository by commands below

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/leveldb/libleveldb1v5_1.20-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libleveldb1v5_1.20-2_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/minetest/minetest-data_0.4.16+repack-4_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./minetest-data_0.4.16+repack-4_all.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/minetest/minetest_0.4.16+repack-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./minetest_0.4.16+repack-4_amd64.deb
```

and pin/lock their versions by single long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-minetest
Package: minetest-data
Pin: version 0.4.16+repack-4
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: minetest
Pin: version 0.4.16+repack-4
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

to prevent their upgrade.

Comment: that is awesome!  Cannot wait to show the kids tomorrow morning.  This is exactly what I was hoping would be possible.  Thanks.